# CSS centering issue

Tags: html, css, layout, centering

i'm creating a responsive layout but i'm noticing a centering problem. I have three div (three boxes, each one next to the other) and i put them into a parent div to make the alignment. The strange thing is that on dreamweaver all works perfectly, but when i open the HTML file to test the page locally the centering is not correct. Here's the images so that you can understand better.

**On Dreamweaver**
[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaL2k.png)

**When i open the HTML page locally**
[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bl1b3.png)

In the first screen as you can see, right and left spaces are perfectly equal, in the second screen left space is more narrow. I'd love to know why on dreamweaver is ok. Here's the code i used.

```
    #infoInner {
    margin-left: 0.5%;
    margin-right: -0.5%;
  }

  .boxInfo {
    padding: 2% 2%;
    margin: 0 1.5%;
    width: 26%;
    border: 1px dashed white;
    float: left;
  }
```

Comment: How is your framework handling the default styles added by the browser? Also, what browser you are using to view the page locally?

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand your first question. Anyway i tried with IE, Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers by default tend to add styles to the document. This is why projects such as [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) exist to remove them, however, this is not the solution to your problem.

When a web browser displays code, it's the [rendering engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_browser_engine) that interprets the code to then lays it out to the screen. Chrome uses Blink, Safari uses Webkit, Internet Explorer uses Trident, and so on. After a bit of research, I see that Dreamweaver used the Presto rendering engine until version 3, and then moved to Webkit on version 4 / 5. I am not sure about the version DW6, I am also going to assume it is Webkit **(EDIT WELCOMED)**. You should receive a similar result if you open your code up in Safari.

I recommend you open a new question with your code represented in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for members of SO to help you out and get it the way you want to look. However, from the description and the code posted it seems to be a rendering issue.

**Further Reading:**

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_browser_engine
- http://mashable.com/2014/02/26/browser-testing-tools/
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7bs9RGolIyI (More for the comedy)

Comment: Thank you very much for spending time trying to solve my problem. Ok, i'll try in this way, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do that on this way:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item center"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>

.wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.wrapper .item {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
    width: 32%;
    margin: 0px;
}

.wrapper .item.center{
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
}
```

I hope this help! :)

Comment: Thank you for your code, but if i put inline instead of float i obtain a bad layout. Anyway i think the best way to solve this is to understand why all works fine on dreamweaver and non locally.

Comment: Sorry for adding this comment just now, but i forgot to ask you: there's a way to add a rendering engine in the HTML/CSS project?